# Sistema de inventario C++

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un programa en c++ que consiste en un sistema de inventario,se me pide el siguiente menú :

1. Introducir un artículo
2. Modificar un artículo
3. Eliminar un artículo
4. Listar el inventario
5. Listar inventario de productos agotados
6. Salir del programa

Por ahora en este caso solo estoy trabajando la opción de introducir un articulo
y se me piden los siguientes requisitos para la creación de un articulo:

- a) Código
- b) Descripción
- c) Costo

Para lo cual he creado el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int NE,i=0,R;
string vector[50];

do{

cout<<"1.Introducir articulo\n2.Modificar un articulo\n3.Eliminar un articulo\n4.Listar el inventario\n5.Listar inventario de productos agotados\n6.Salir del programa\n";
cin>>NE;
system("cls");


switch(NE){
    case 1:
        i++;

        cout<<"Ingrese nombre del articulo\n";
        cin>>vector[i];


        cout<<"El nombre de articulo es:"<<vector[i]<<"\n";
            break;



    default:
    cout<<"Opcion aun no disponible\n"; 



    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Desea regresar al menu principal?\n";
    cout<<"Y. N.\n";
    cin>>R; 
}while(R=='Y');


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Como pueden ver he declarado un vector de 50 espacios que por el momento sólo almacenara el nombre del articulo a introducir,ademas de tener una estructura cíclica "do while" y un iterador "i" que servirá para guardar los nombres de diferentes artículos en diferentes espacios de memoria cada vez que el proceso vuelva a repetirse,pero mi problema es que al terminar de introducir y guardar el nombre de un articulo y querer volver a repetir el proceso para introducir otro articulo mi "do while" no funciona y el programa se cierra,perdiéndose así los datos del vector, cualquier ayuda o consejo es bienvenido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con `cin >> R` estás pidiendo un entero, cuando deberías de pedir un caracter (para Y/N).

Cambia el tipo de tu variable, y todo debería funcionar:

```
char R;
```